# Upgrading Firefox on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, installation

I'd like to upgrade my Firefox on Ubuntu to the latest version. I downloaded the file `firefox-16.0.2.tar.bz2` and unpacked it, but I don't see any instructions on how to install it. What should I do?

Comment: does 'sudo apt-get install firefox' or 'sudo apt-get install firefox=16.0.2' not work?

but usually in terms of installing packages-the standard method (usually there are directions in a file called INSTALL), usually one uses './configure' to configure the package to work for their system then they use 'make' to compile it. and 'make install' to install it. You need to make sure you have the g++ compiler installed though I remember ubuntu not having it installed by default.

Comment: Ok it works.. sorry I'm new to Ubuntu. Didn't know I should install that way.

Comment: to save you from future problems (if you don't have aptitude) install it "sudo apt-get install aptitude"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is not a test PC or if you want any kind of maintainability then do not install from a tarball. De-installing it later (e.g. because you want to upgrade to the next version) might be hard.

Instead use `aptitude` or another package manager.

If you tried that and it did not list firefox try `deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main` to add the repository.

If you want to download a package manual, try [http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-locale-en_16.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.10.1_amd64.deb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/amd64/firefox-locale-en/download)